# Is there a way to represent conditionals assuming absolute value of the item in the cell for custom number formats?

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I am making a spreadsheet for an MMO that has currencies split up in gold (g), silver (s), and copper (c). `10,000c = 100s = 1g.` I would like to do all my calculations in copper to avoid decimals (any value under a copper can be rounded either way for visuals sake, I don't really care), but I want them to be shown formatted into gold, silver, and copper amounts.

I would like to have a way to format my numbers such that:

1. `1234567 = 123g 45s 67c`
2. `12345 = 1g 23s 45c`
3. `2345 = 23s 45c`
4. `45 = 45c`
5. `-45 = -45c`
6. `-2345 = -23s 45c`
7. `-12345 = -1g 23s 45c`
8. `-1234567 = -123g 45s 67c`

I currently have a format `[<100]#"c ";[>=10000]#"g "##"s "##"c ";#"s "##"c ";` that does the job when all the values are positive. However, when the value is negative, everything gets shown as copper `instead of being split up. There are many cases in my spreadsheet where it is unknown whether the value will be positive or negative. Is it possible to assume someway that we want the conditional to be against the absolute value? Or at least use a placeholder as a variable to represent the value in the cell?

`[|x|<100]` or `[-100<x<100]` and `[-10000 < x <=-100] && [100 <= x < 10000]`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

internal formatting is not so versatile so there are some downsides tho...

```
[<10000]#"g "##"s "##"c ";[>=10000]#"g "##"s "##"c "
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the options are pretty limited, I looked around and I couldn't find anything so I hoped someone could prove my googling wrong.